Running wrong or correct c code displays same problem on terminal:
"C:/msys64/clang64/bin/mingw32-make.exe" not recognised as internal or external command

I tried to change many settings. The program works on vs code, mingw is correctly installed.
The "hello world" program does not display anything on terminal. Once it worked but I don't know why. Since then, I reinstalled many times codelite and mingw.

Maybe you once had C:/msys64/clang64/bin/mingw32-make.exe and it's missing now?
